# Taylor's Theorem in two different forms? in Numerical Optimization book by Jorge Nocedal

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, numerical-optimization

This is the Taylor's Theorem

$f(x)=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+R_2$

I am not sure how it relates to the formulas below, which is shown in Numerical Optimization book by Jorge Nocedal and Stephen J. Wright.

$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x+tp)^\top p$

for some $t\in(0,1)$, and if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, we can have

$\nabla f(x+p)=\nabla f(x)+\int_0^1\nabla^2f(x+tp)p~dt$

thus we can have

$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^\top p+\frac{1}{2}p^\top\nabla^2f(x+tp)p$

Why is the function becomes $f(x+p)$? and what is the use of $t$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: One is for $\mathbb{R}$ , the other is for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The second equation in your second link is basically the twice differentiable and multivariable version of your first link.

Comment: but why we need to add a $p$ in the argument of the function? as I saw the multivariate taylor's is also just $f(x)$, where $x$ is a vector

Comment: Where the first formula has $(a,x,x-a)$, the second formula has $(x,x+p,p)$. Note that $t$ is the scalar parameter along the segment from $x$ to $x+p$.

Comment: i see, but how does the $R_2$ term become something in terms of $t$ ?

Comment: You evaluate the Hessian at a point on the line segment between $x$ and $x+p$, which is basically the same as evaluating the second derivative at a point between $a$ and $x$ in the one dimensional context. Indeed you could write the 1D case in terms of $f''(a+t(x-a))$ if you wanted, it is just not really any more convenient.